# L is language generated by the context free grammar G = (V, $\Sigma$, P, S)

Tags: context-free-grammar, regular-expressions

L is language generated by the context free grammar G = (V, $\Sigma$, P, S), where $\Sigma$ = {a,b,c}, V = {S, A, B}, and the production set P is:

S -> aSb | A

A -> cAb | B

B -> cb

My question is, can the following belong to L?

accbbbcb?

i think it does because:

accbbb = S -> aSb -> acBbb -> accbbb
cb = B -> cb
so, concatenating both, accbbbcb.

Maybe this is a too elementary question, but just wanted to check. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\aa}{\mathtt{a}}\newcommand{\bb}{\mathtt{b}}\newcommand{\cc}{\mathtt{c}}$No, $\aa\cc\cc\bb\bb\bb\cc\bb$ does *not* belong to $L$. Your concatenation does not make sense. Your language is 
$$ L = \{\aa^i\cc^k\cc\bb\bb^k\bb^i \mid i \leq 1 \} = \{\aa^i\cc^{k+1}\bb^{k+i+1} \mid i \leq 1\}. $$

Observe, that the letters appear sorted: $\aa$, $\cc$ and then $\bb$, so $\aa\cc\cc\bb\bb\bb$ could be an element of $L$ (and it is, as you already proved), but $\aa\cc\cc\bb\bb\bb\cc\bb$ could not (and it is not).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: so when V = {S,A,B} this does not mean that you can use S and B to create a string? U need to choose one? because for my question, if u choose S and B and concatentate SB, u can come up w/ . Thanks!

Comment: There is only one starting symbol, and in your case it is $S$ (the last symbol in $\langle V, \Sigma, P, S \rangle$). See the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar).